# html header setting

Tags: java, caching

I am java developer. I need to know how  to set expiration time for caching.

Any help is appreciated.

Is there any best way to do this?

Comment: are you using any specific cache library, or is this one of those general vague questions?

Answer (score 0):

here is how you can do it on the client side:
RESPONSE.setHeader('Cache-Control', 'max-age=86400, s-maxage=86400, public, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate')

here is more info and examples:
[source and example:](https://weblion.psu.edu/trac/weblion/changeset/14552)